# Check if NSWindow currently in zoomed state?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

Is there a robust way of checking whether the window is currently in its maximized zoom state?

I'm not looking for a notification or delegate method that would tell me **when** the `NSWindow` changes its size but need to check at some point whether the current size is the maximized state.

Couldn't find anything straight-forward on `NSWindow` to achieve that..

Comment: To quote a wise woman, "Why do you need to know?"  There may be a better way to accomplish what you're really trying to solve.

Comment: @jeffamaphone pretty special requirement I suppose - adding a transparant overlay window that surrounds my window on all sides for some visual candy. If main window is zoomed to max then some drawing is not visible..

Comment: Oh dear Jehova God Almighty every freaking time I stumble upon a Cocoa question on any website or forum there's a guy who promptly asks "why do you need to know?" and "maybe there's another way". Dear Jesus kill me now, strike a lightning, drop the chandelier on my head, do something.

Comment: "I want to draw a red circle". "Oh, that's an odd request, why would you need such silly thing? Maybe there's another way. Whay don't you tell us what you _really_ want."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `zoomed` property of the window, whose getter is `-isZoomed`.

Prior to the 10.10 SDK, this was an informal property. Its getter method was declared directly. There was no related `@property` declaration. Apple converted a lot of such properties from informal to "declared properties" in the 10.10 SDK. In some cases, the old, stand-alone methods are listed as "deprecated" in the documentation, but that's just a side effect of the conversion. The getter method is still there, still named the same, still callable, and not deprecated. Just the mechanism by which it was declared has changed.

Answer (score 1):

> Well, isZoomed is available on 10.0 to 10.9, but... since you're asking this question, I guess you're probably on 10.10, wondering why it's not there.  :)
>
> But look at the "discussion" part of the Apple docs for isZoomed:
>
> ..snip..

Or maybe don't look at the docs in this case. :) See Ken Thomases' answer.

Comment: This is incorrect, although understandable due to Apple's buggy documentation. The `-isZoomed` method is still valid, it's just changed from being declared directly to being part of a "declared property" using `@property` with the `getter=` attribute. See my answer.